# Can't retrieve post values

Tags: post, laravel, routes

I'm trying to create an API in Laravel to integrate a game with a backend app.
The game needs to post an username and a password, and i'll create a token to this session use this API.
I'll tried Route::post, Route::any, but when I send a request, with method POST using SoapUI or REST Console (chrome plugin), Input::get('any') returns nothing. 
When i send a request with method GET, it works.
I not found a solution on Web.

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    Route::any('/gamelogin', 'ApiController@login');    
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'v1', 'before' => 'apitoken'), function() {
        Route::get('/milestone', array('uses' => 'ApiController@milestone'));   
    }); 
});
```

filters.php

```
Route::filter('apitoken', function() {
    // check if apitoken is valid
});
```

ApiController.php

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

    public function login()  {

        try {

            $statusCode = 200;


            $response = [
              'status'  =>  [
                                'code' => 1,
                                'message' => 'Usuário ou senha inválidos'
                            ]
            ];

            $userdata = array(
                'login'     => Input::get('login'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password'),      
                'active'    => '1'      
                );


            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

                // TODO: verificar licença              
                $response['status'] = null;
                $response['token'] = md5('id'.date('YmdHis'));
                $response['api'] = 'v1'; 
                $response['assets_url'] = 'games.xpto.com.br/'.Input::get('game').'/v1/'.'pt_br/';
                $response['assets_version'] = 1;

            } 

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $statusCode = 400;

        } finally {

            return Response::json($response, $statusCode);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code and Route::any() or Route::post() should be catching any POST request. Perhaps what you might try is just catching a POST request outside of Laravel from your application and see if it is coming through that way.

Comment: Check `Input::all()` is returning the request input - `Input::get('any')` is actually looking for a request parameter called `any`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. 
The code is correct, but i didn't know that i need to configure in testing tools (rest console for example) a parameter named raw body, and set the parameter value as JSON.